# How to remove overlapping sequences from two datatables?

Tags: r, performance, data.table, genomicranges

I have two data.tables that provide sequence coordinates across different chromosomes (categories). For example:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(chromosome = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "X"),
                  start = c(1, 50, 110, 150, 110),
                  end = c(11, 100, 121, 200, 200))
dt2 <- data.table(chromosome = c("1", "1", "X"),
                  start = c(12, 60, 50),
                  end = c(20, 115, 80))
```

I need to create a third data.table that provides coordinates for sequences that contain all the integers in dt1 that do not overlap with any integers from the sequences in dt2. For example:

```
dt3 <- data.table(chromosome = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "X"),
                  start = c(1, 50, 116, 150, 110),
                  end = c(11, 59, 121, 200, 200))
```

The data.tables I need to run this on are very large and therefore I need to maximise performance. I have tried using the foverlaps() function but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start with something like this from `foverlaps`

```
setkey(dt2,chromosome,start,end)
ds = foverlaps(dt1,dt2,  type="any")
ds[,.(chromosome, 
      start = fcase(is.na(start) | i.start <= start,i.start,
                    i.end >= end, end + 1),
      end = fcase(is.na(end) | i.end >= end, i.end,
                  i.start <= start, start - 1)
      )]
#   chromosome start   end
#       <char> <num> <num>
#1:          1     1    11
#2:          1    50    59
#3:          1   116   121
#4:          1   150   200
#5:          X   110   200
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, there is a concise solution using the `GenomicRanges` packages from Bioconductor:

```
library(GenomicRanges)
setdiff(makeGRangesFromDataFrame(dt1), makeGRangesFromDataFrame(dt2))
```

> ```
> GRanges object with 5 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
>       seqnames    ranges strand
>          <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle>
>   [1]        1      1-11      *
>   [2]        1     50-59      *
>   [3]        1   116-121      *
>   [4]        1   150-200      *
>   [5]        X   110-200      *
>   -------
>   seqinfo: 2 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
> ```

---

In case the result is required to be of class `data.table`:

```
library(data.table) # development version 1.14.3 used
library(GenomicRanges)
setdiff(makeGRangesFromDataFrame(dt1), makeGRangesFromDataFrame(dt2)) |> 
  as.data.table() |>
  DT(, .(chromosome = seqnames, start, end))
```

> ```
>    chromosome start   end
>        <fctr> <int> <int>
> 1:          1     1    11
> 2:          1    50    59
> 3:          1   116   121
> 4:          1   150   200
> 5:          X   110   200
> ```

---

As [mentioned by Waldi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483021/how-to-remove-overlapping-sequences-from-two-datatables/70491054#comment124609909_70491054), the `GenomicRanges` package is not available from CRAN. Waldi has provided [the link to the installation guide in the `BiocManager` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BiocManager/vignettes/BiocManager.html). Here is the short version:

```
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("GenomicRanges")
```

Comment: As `GenomicRanges` isn't on CRAN, this link explains [how to install BioConductor Packages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BiocManager/vignettes/BiocManager.html)